# Acrescentar X dias em uma data já predefinida no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Preciso criar uma data limite, uma data de expiração de acesso

no caso estou utilizando pra captar o hora atual o

```
"criado" datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Onde utilizo o CURRENT_TIMESTAMP pra conseguir da hora da gravação no MySQL, depois do criado tbm tem o "EXPIRA"

Como posso acrescentar dias pra que no expira tenha 30 dias a mais que o criado?

Ex2: Criou hoje ( 13/02/2017 ) e vai expirar amanhã(+1 dia) // minha questão é nesse +1 dia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `DATE_ADD(criado,INTERVAL 10 DAY)` vai adicionar 10dias em cima do valor do campo `criado`

Comment: Obrigado! funcionou